# Modify a IMG inside a class array? document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[0] li img;

Tags: javascript, html

```
#videoslider .navigation li img{
transition: 0.3s;
width: 120px !important;
height: 70px;
```

How can i reach and modify my IMG inside the list of the videoslider class?
I expected somethign like this:

```
var sliderNaviImg = document.getElementsByClassName('navigation')[0] li img;
```

but i could not get any result out of this.

Does anyone know how to handle this?

EDIT:

```
<ul class="navigation">
    <li onclick="videoselector('https://feluction.de/wp-content/uploads/2023/01/Trailer_169_TS0RF_WO.mp4')"><img src="https://felixa/wp-content/uploadsarnberg.jpg"></li>
    <li onclick="videoselector('https://felip-content/uploaler_169_Golf_HD_10RF_WO.mp4')"><img src="https://felixandstefd2_thumb.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I assume navigation is the `<ul>` or `<ol>` so then you need to look at `sliderNavImg.children[0].children[0]` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children)

Comment: So it should be something like `sliderNaviImg.li[0].img[0].height = "20px";` ?

Comment: Ah now. Its really simple like `sliderNavImg.children[0].children[0]`